# Ecomdev_PHPUnit not loading custom attributes

Tags: attributes, ecomdev-phpunit, phpunit

I am dropping the test database before invoking `phpunit` in Ecomdev_PHPUnit.

It creates the database and it's not importing user attributes from `eav_attribute`.

Is it safe to just clone the real database to a test one ? I can't find the code responsible for attribute loading in Ecomdev's.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your custom attribute is not imported may be that you didn't write an upgrade script creating the attribute. EcomDev_PHPUnit doesn't copy the database but runs the normal Magento scripts.

When PHPUnit is started the EcomDev extensions kicks in with `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Test_Listener::startTestSuite()`. This method invokes `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Model_App::applyTestScope()` and this one calls `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Model_App::initTest()`.

`EcomDev_PHPUnit_Model_App::initTest()` launches the normal install/upgrade script process by executing `Mage_Core_Model_App::_initModules()`.

This means you can either

1. write upgrade scripts for attributes,
2. use fixtures or
3. copy the database.

As far as I know (I'm still new to EcomDev_PHPUnit myself) your options for EAV attributes are number 1 and 3.

I didn't try copying the database yet but it should work. **I'd go with option 1**. Writing upgrade scripts for attribute sets, groups and attributes can be much work but it is a best practice and there is a high probability it will pay off in multiple ways (less manual setup for other projects / working copies, better transparency, ...). This [nifty script by Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_attribute_migration_generator) may be of help.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I ended up cloning the database, and rewrote the store from scratch for 1.9 this time using the UI for attributes. The link with script seems good, I'll keep that.